# Image as TabIndicator

Tags: java, android

using a image as tabIndicator it always appears at the center i want it to take up the whole space available in that tab can I make it something like fill parent ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//in your xml Image attribute as

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or //using thru programatically

```
imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```